# PHP Preg_match_all in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, preg-match

I've got this php code that works perfectly:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/<div style="display:block; float:left; height:240px; width:150px;'
    . ' text-align:center; margin:5px; overflow:hidden;">.*?'
    . '<span class="card-text">(.*?)'
    . '<span class="instruction">\((.*?)\)<\/span>/s',
  $html,
  $students,
  PREG_SET_ORDER
);

foreach($students as $student) {
  echo($student[1].",".$student[2]."<br />");
}
```

How would I do this in javascript? Thanks!

Comment: in javascript do you have a string with the html or are you traversing the DOM properly? If you are doing this with the DOM (what I would suggest), you would use a completely different method where you would use DOM functions like `document.getElementById` and `parent.getElementsByTagName` then loop through those results.

Comment: It's a string, a very long one. about 500K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frankly you should **not** do this using JavaScript. You should not be trying to parse so much HTML using regular expressions either.

Instead you should consider looking at something like [Simple HTML Dom parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

As for a JavaScript solution - **JS is a DOM parser!**

```
var student1 = document.getElementsByClassName('card-text')[0];
var student2 = document.getElementsByClassName('instruction')[0];
//echo out
```

A better solution would be to use jQuery, since you'll have fewer problems with DOM manipulation (its selector engine is fantastic!) [see rough example here](http://jsfiddle.net/xv5LB/1/).

Comment: I'm actually using jquery for other parts of the project, thanks for the quick example, I'll take a look at it.